# VBA leave object created opened after procedure finished

Tags: vba, excel

Observe the follow code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myObj as Object
    Set myObj = CreateObject("ABC.Application")
    myObj.visible = TRUE
End Sub
```

The application ABC was closed after the procedure finished.  How do i leave it opened ? I tried `Set myObj = Nothing` but didn't work.

Comment: Is this behavior exclusive to the application. I ran the same lines of code using `Word.Application` as the object type and Microsoft Word stayed open after the procedure ended.

Comment: How is this working at all? Usually you'd have to use `Set` for objects (`Set myObj = CreateObject(...)`)

Comment: @EngJon: Sure, amended

Comment: The application will not close unless you are trying to close it somewhere in your code or say manually closing it. The object `myObj` however is not available for other procedure unless you re-assign it.  BTW what application is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `Dim myObj As Object` statement, which is declared in local scope.

I try to explain with an example:

```
Dim a As Object '<-- global declaration
Sub mySub()
    Dim b As Object 'local declaration
End Sub
```

The difference between `a` and `b` is the scope: while `a` has a global scope, `b` has a local one. Which means:

1. `b` will be collected by the garbage collector (hence destroyed) once the scope of the routine is gone (i.e. at the end of the execution)
2. `a`, instead, will **not** be collected as garbage after the execution because its scope is global (i.e. living until the hosting process lives).

You should be able to fix it declaring the `Object` globally:

```
Dim myObj as Object '<-- it will "survive" even after execution
Sub test()
    Set myObj = CreateObject("ABC.Application")
    myObj.visible = TRUE
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds legit. But, as user3561813 pointed out in a comment to the OP, a word application stays open despite being declared locally. So, why is this not affecting `Word.Application`?

Comment: @EngJon I must test, you might be right. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @user3354000, can we know the exact type of application you're trying to create?

Comment: @EngJon: The application remains open but the Object is no longer there as it was declared inside the procedure. Try what Matt has suggested in the above post.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, due to the local scope you can't interact with this application. However, it still remains opened after the Sub has ended and I think that OP's question was intended to get a solution doing that (although not for a Word-Application). So I'm still wondering why Word stays open while other applications close.

Comment: @EngJon: You have lost me there:)  `So I'm still wondering why Word stays open while other applications close.` Um which other applications?

Comment: @EngJon:  btw my apologies, I confused you with the OP :D And hence I asked you instead of OP to try it...

Comment: @SiddharthRout The original application from OP. Namely `ABC.Application` (yet there was no answer given to what application it is).  Following the question, it closes after the Sub has ended. edit: no problem with the confusion ;)

Comment: it is not an MS office application; Matt's solution works.  However, if my procedure will close the workbook itself as well, how do i keep ABC application remains opened? Edit: Sorry for being unable to tell what exact ly ABC is.

Comment: Here is all a big mess of processes. My idea (not verified, so I write it here in a comment) is that Office applications start on a new thread; hence, even if the reference is collected for garbage, the application lives because lies into its self thread. However, Office's thread is not able to make a parallel thread on external applications, hence it holds the thread within the same process launched by the VBA project. And that should be why the difference, but again: this is not verified so please don't take it as an answer :)

Comment: @user3354000 if what I say in my above comment is true, I fear there's no way to hold it open. But what you can do (if you really cannot say what ABC is), if you only need to launch the application without interacting with it, then you might launch it by cmd so the operating system will create a separate thread and all problems are solved even after Office termination.